# Comparing runtime complexities for n^a * log(n)^b and n^c*log(n)^d

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I'm working on a problem where I am given f(n) = n^2 * (log(n))^-1, and g(n) = n(log(n))^2, and asked to determine whether f=O(g), f=omega(g), or both (f=theta(g)).

This problem can be generalized to (n^a)*log(n)^b and (n^c)*log(n)^d

I understand that any polynomial dominates any logarithm, for example n dominates log(n) and furthermore n^2 dominates nlog(n) however I am unsure about how to adapt this to more complicated problems, for example:

- f = (n^2)*log(n)^-1000, g = (n)*log(n)^1000

or better yet:

- f = n^.01, g = log(n)^10

*Does the polynomial term always determine if f dominates g, or vise versa? If so, why? and if not, how can the problem be solved?*

Thanks!

Comment: Polylog is always less than polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: `n^a * log(n)^b` dominates `n^c * log(n)^d` if `a > c`. In other words, you only need to look at the polynomial part. (Unless of course `a=c`, in which case you look at the polylog part.)

This is because polylogarithmic functions are always asymptotically less than polynomial functions. More precisely, if `p(n) = a*(log n)^b` (`p` is polylogarithmic in `n`), then `p(n) = o(n^epsilon)` for any `epsilon > 0` (see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithmic_function) for the formal statement, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1663823) for a proof).

So, we have `n^a * log(n)^b = o(n^(a + epsilon))` for any `epsilon > 0`. From this it should be easy to arrive at the answer above.

Comment: Might also be helpful to quote [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial).

Comment: Forgot to say thanks for the help on this! Cheers

Comment: @JSMorgan Accepting an answer is the standard way of showing you liked it :)

Comment: Done - didn't know about that feature until now.